# Open Source Java library for conversion to HTML?

Tags: java, html, open-source

I know there are some Java libraries to create PDF files and the likes, but does anybody know of a Java library to convert various file formats to HTML, especially PDF and MS Word files?

The purpose of this is to display a file preview in the web browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) allows programmatic access to the Office documents and in particular their conversion to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a collection of PDF libraries(and more) at [java-source.net](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries). I would recommend iText.